# How to use NSEntityDescription with a project that was not created with use CoreData checked

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to save high score data for users that play my card game. I want to use CoreData to save and load that data but I am very new to swift programming and CoreData in general and my project was created well before I knew I wanted to use CoreData and the easiest way to import it is to check the 'use CoreData' box. So here is my **ViewController** code (only the important parts of course)

```
    var trackTapCount = 0
    private var managedContext:NSManagedObjectContext!
    private var entityDescription:NSEntityDescription!
    private var scoreData: NSManagedObject!
    var capturedData = [Score]()
    var storedInitials: String = ""
    var storedTime: String = ""
    var sessionData = Score(username: "", completionTime: 0, numTurns: 0, dateTimestamp: "")
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let saveAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        managedContext = saveAppDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext

//        managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()// Does this work?
        
        entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ScoreData", in: managedContext)
        
//
//        scoreData = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: managedContext)
     
    }
```

My **AppDelegate** code

```
            /*
             The persistent container for the application. This implementation
             creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
             application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
             error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
             */
            let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "BoschBrooke_4.1_MemoryGame")
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                    
                    /*
                     Typical reasons for an error here include:
                     * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                     * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                     * The device is out of space.
                     * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                     */
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            })
            return container
        }()
        
        // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
        
        func saveContext () {
            let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
            if context.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }
```

And finally, my Entity setup looks like the following:
E: ScoreData
Attributes:

- initials Type: String
- tapCount Type: Integer 16
- timeComplete Type: String
- timestamp Type: String

Any idea how I can use the NSEntityDescription and NSManagedObject to save my data properly? One of the big issues I am running into is at the entityDescription line in my ViewController. It's saying '*unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value*'.

Comment: You can manually add a Core Data model to your project using New (cmd+F) and selecting the right template. The easiest way to get the persistence controller class you get for free with a Core Data project is to create a new project with Core Data enabled and then copy the class from there. Once that is done you have what you need to start using Core Data

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joakim. I transferred those functions (persistentContainer and saveContext) awhile back. I had no issues there. The main problem I am having now is with the NSEntityDescription and the NSManagedObject

Comment: I don’t really understand why you need to use NSEntityDescription and  NSManagedObject in viewDidLoad like that